# Why aren't Semantic UI functions working in the Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I have a **Slider** element (I'm actually using the **Fomantic UI** fork, which has slider as well).
I am writing `<script>jQuery("mysliderid").slider();</script>` immediately after the slider HTML and it works!

However, if I write `jQuery("mysliderid").slider();` in console, the slider is not working! It's also not working if I include the code in a separate .js file.

It makes no sense to me. I have no idea how to debug it.

The context is that I'm writing a Wordpress plugin

Comment: Check what's $.slider() is returning on console. Also check the page source if the js file loaded correctly.

Comment: Thank you Aamir. The JS is loading (`console.log('it's loading!'`) shows up). The $.slider() returns no error, looks as if it's working. But the slider/additional html/slider tick and bar are not showing up.

Comment: Make sure you have added css file, sometimes controls not render as expected because of missing css.